# Android Studio error: “Environment variable does not point to a valid JVM installation”

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, installation, java-home

I am installing android studio into my 32 bit windows.
It was installed when i am going to launch this application it was giving error of the **java_home environment variable does not point to a valid jvm installation**

I have checked the version installed on PC.[screenshot of java version and path where it was installed on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8YTh.png)

My Android Studio Folder which was build doesn't created JRE Folder.[Path where Android Studio has setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sj17.png) .

Comment: It was looking for a C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre in the error, but this root directory is not build ed during installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio error: "Environment variable does not point to a valid JVM instalation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185358/android-studio-error-environment-variable-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jvm-instal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake which i have done is that i am giving JAVA_HOME variable to System Variables not to User Variable.

so, we have to give a variable to a User Variable in environment variable.

second thing is that the value should only has a path of a jdk not other paths are added in that value.In my case it was also storing other path also don't know why??but now working.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

Select **Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties**.

Then open **Advanced tab > Environment Variables** and add a new system variable **JAVA_HOME** that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79.

Comment: do i need to change in User Variable of my PC??

Comment: Yes. You need to add a new environment variable, call it JAVA_HOME and give it the path to your JDK, like in the example.

Comment: thanks for the reply but JAVA_HOME is already there and it also has some value.Should i change it to my JDk path?

Comment: Yes, you should change it to your JDK path.

Comment: should i overwrite on previous path or i can say value which was there ?

It not affect other things right??

Comment: Well the previous path obviously isn't correct, just overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah thanks buddy

now i think it was in working mode atleast gone to next step.

Thanks man,

Now it was saying  SDK tools directory is missing

Comment: No problem mate, close this thread tho, because this problem was fixed. If you cannot figure out how to proceed after this, consider searching for the new problem or posting it here separately.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Computer->Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab 
-> Environmental variables button click ->
Add JAVA_HOME variable to user variables section like bellow screen grab.

[image]

Then open up the path variable under the system variables. Edit it and add JAVA_HOME at he end of the line like the bellow image.

[image]

Comment: Anyway it will help others

Answer (score 0):

if you install the  jdk1.7.0_79  and add environment variable path to add the path  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the response, my operating system is 64bits, I tried to open the android-studio  32bits, I try to install a 32bits version of java, but got the response, I went to a bin folder Of Android studio, and opened the 64bits executable, worked correctly, with my java_home pointing to 64bits logically.

[image]

Then the confirmation looks like this:

Environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx
```

Opening android studio:

```
studio64.exe
```